# Возможен ли произвольный шрифт текста на сайте?

Tags: php, html

Суть: делаю дизайнерскую страничку на php, где желательно бы весь текст выводить красивым готичным шрифтом. Однако понятное дело, у 90% юзеров такого шрифта на компах нет, и всю его красоту они не оценят =/  Есть ли возможность, скажем, загрузить шрифт к себе на сервер, и где-то прописать на страничке, чтобы он подгружался оттуда?  Знаю, что в php-рисовалках баннеров и прочих юзербаров такое возможно, но у меня текст не пишется в изображение, а просто висит на страничке, кое-где подгружаясь из БД. Вид:

```
echo 'Знаете ли вы о';
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo ''.$row[1].',';
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo 'который возник в '.$row[2].'';
```

и т.д. В общем, есть ли какие-то варианты, или увы мне?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть вариант: использовать [font-face](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face). Конечно, это не кроссбраузерный вариант, но текст будет показан в любом случае.
Также, можно использовать [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/). Тогда текст будет выводиться javascript'ом в виде картинки (создается "на лету").

Answer (score 3):

можно использовать Google Web Fonts 
http://www.google.com/webfonts

там же есть не сложная инструкция как всем этим пользоваться.